# wsprint how to use with TCHAR

Tags: c++

I am not able to print in log file

```
CString strCmdLine = GetCommandLine();
WCHAR strLogData[80];
CString strFormat;`

WCHAR strExeName[40];
WCHAR strCmdParameter[40],
WCHAR strToolName[40];
WCHAR strAuthcode[40];
WCHAR strUsername[40];
WCHAR strUtilityVersion[40];
WCHAR strPCID[40];

strFormat = _T("%[^ ],%[^ ],%[^ ],%[^ ],%[^ ]");`
swscanf_s(strCmdLine, strFormat, strExeName, sizeof(strExeName),
          strCmdParameter, sizeof(strCmdParameter), strToolName, 
          sizeof(strToolName), strAuthcode, sizeof(strAuthcode),
          strUsername, sizeof(strUsername), strUtilityVersion, 
          sizeof(strUtilityVersion), strPCID, sizeof(strPCID));

wsprintf(strLogData,_T("Launching RTOP DELETE UTILITY - %s"), strUtilityVersion);
m_pLogFile->AppendLogData(strLogData);
```

`strUtilityVersion` is not printed to the log file.

Comment: Please take some time and [edit] your question and make your code readable. And please take the [tour] and read this: [ask]

Comment: Check the number of conversion specifiers in your `strFormat` against the number of arguments provided for `swscanf_s()`.

Comment: yes that Is one mistake I have edited that but still not working

Comment: I am not getting correct way to split it.. my strCmdLine string is in below format  abc "cde" "efg" "hij" "klm" "nop" "qus"